# How to convert this sql statement to linq with this pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

How to convert this sql statement to linq.

```
declare @S nvarchar(100) = 'www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i'

while PATINDEX('%[/]%' , @S) > 0 BEGIN
    SET @S = LEFT (@S,LEN(@S) - PATINDEX('%[/]%' , REVERSE(@S)))
SELECT @S
END
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string url = "www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i";

var q = url.Split('/').Select(s => sb.Append((sb.Length > 0 ? "/" : "") + s).ToString());

foreach(string output in q.Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

**Output:**

```
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d
www.abc.com/a/b/c
www.abc.com/a/b
www.abc.com/a
www.abc.com
```